# PHP export array data into column of data in CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export nationality data into CSV. My nationality data are stored in an array. However, when i export it out, my CSV output show this error **"**Warning**:  fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array"**. Can I know how i can show my nationality data in a csv column?

**my code:**

```
$filename = "nationality_list.csv"; // Create file name
$array_nat = array('BANGLADESH','CAMBODIA','CHINESE','DUTCH','FILIPINO','FRENCH','GERMAN','INDIAN','INDONESIA','ITALY','JAPANESE','KOREAN','LITHUANIAN','MALAYSIA','MYANMAR','NEW ZEALAND','RUSSIAN','SINGAPOREAN','SRI LANKAN','THAILAND','UK','USA');
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

$fields = array('Nationality_list');
        
fputcsv($f, $fields);
    
foreach($array_nat as $nat){
    fputcsv($f, $nat);
}

//move back to beginning of file
fseek($f, 0);
//set headers to download file rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
//output all remaining data on a file pointer
fpassthru($f)
```

**Desired output in CSV**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fputcsv($f, [$nat]);
```

fputcsv expects an array because a row consists of n columns. 1 in your case :)